# Why can't I install 'arm64' packages on an 'amd64' system when I can install 'armhf' packages?

Tags: 16.04, apt, 64-bit, arm, arm64

Pretty self-explanatory: could someone tell me why I get the error

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-6-base:arm64
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-6-base_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 package architecture (arm64) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-6-base_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-6-base:armhf
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-6-base:armhf.
(Reading database ... 219445 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-6-base_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-6-base:armhf (6.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcc-6-base:armhf (6.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
```

works just fine on my AMD64 system? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. You [need to run](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.html#id-1.8.8.9.6):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
```

And you can see the list of existing architectures added via:

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Why they think the user must be initially joking about the explicit `:arm64` suffix is beyond me. It's not like you don't already have to explicilty add `arm64` as an architecture in `/etc/sources.list`...

Comment: How do you explicitly add `arm64` as an architecture in `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Or in my case, `amd64`? I have tried both `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64` and modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` with lines starting with `deb [arch=arm64,amd64] http://us.ports` but apt is not able to find amd64 packages.

Comment: @AaronFranke: Unfortunately I don't know; you might want to ask a separate question.